# Excel VBA: USerform P&L Entered into columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a rookie - good at adapting code, not experienced at developing it from scratch but I am trying to learn. Just need some accelerated help please.

What I have is a P&L userform and I am trying to create some VBA to search for the next blank column and then enter the P&L Label in the first blank column and the P&L value in the second column.

I've started giving it a go however seems to just be going across the row and not down a column. I know this is because ***lRow, 1-7*** range however if I change this to just ***lRow, 1*** for all entries it just overlaps in the one cell. Seems like I may need a loop but I am unsure and a bit out of my depth.

The code I tried so far is just for the label only. Not sure how to incorporate the value into the same VBA when I select "Save" in the column beside it (next blank column).

```
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Database")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.saleslbl
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.costofsaleslbl
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.netincomelbl
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.accountinglbl
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.rentlbl
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.bankfeeslbl
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.utilitieslbl
    End With
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add some screenshots of a "before" and "after" scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the 1st blank column in Excel is an evegreen issue. There are plenty of solutions here on SO. Basically you have 2 options:

1.a.:

```
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = ws.Cells(ws.Columns.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
```

This command will find the column of the **1st empty cell in 1st row** but ignores all other cells in that column.

1.b.:

```
lCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
```

This command will take the column next to the rightmost column ever used in that sheet, regardless of the content, so the column(s) left to the border may also **look** empty.

2. Change the other param of `Cells`, e.g.:

   ```
   .Cells(1, lCol).Value = Me.saleslbl
   .Cells(2, lCol).Value = Me.costofsaleslbl
   ....
   .Cells(1, lCol + 1).Value = Me.salestextbox    ' or whatever is the name of the textbox
   .Cells(2, lCol + 1).Value = Me.costofsalestextbox
   ```